# Как мне в программу встроить установку иных программ и сертификатов?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

хочу на C# написать программку(по типу мульти установщика) в которой можно будет выбирать список программ которые нужно установить или различных сертификатов и желательно чтобы полный набор программ был встроен в мою программу и в дальнейшем планирую реализовать функционал для настройки параметров windows, давать ip и т.д., пожалуйста подскажите на сколько реальна моя идея и в какую сторону двигаться и как можно подробнее объясните если не сложно, буду рад любой информации по моей теме.

Мне это нужно для получения практических навыков написания ПО для работы с windows.

Comment: Очень абстрактный вопрос для SO, ибо тут нету одного решения. Допустим, вот у вас есть сторонняя программа, что там за установщик? Принимает ли он параметры запуска? Может достаточно распаковать в нужную директорию архивы? Тут ведь сами понимаете, установщиков программ уйма, каждый работает по своему. Не, ну конечно вы можете просто запустить из своей программы другой .exe (установщика) и пусть пользователь там сам выбирает что надо, но это бред, особенно если программ сотня. Также вон есть `winget`, который простой командой консоли установит вам почти любой софт, тоже как вариант...

Comment: Программы будут определенные по типу браузера, архиватора, редактора документов и т.д. и вот надеюсь что можно будет задавать параметры в  мастере установки для каждой программы, чтобы запустил установку выбранных программ, а там уже все само бы прокликивалось . Или же если такое сложно реализовать или муторно, то моя бы программа просто запускала установщики и пользователь сам бы прокликивал, но открывались бы они друг за другом, а не все сразу. вот как то так, надеюсь понятно

Comment: такой софт уже есть - https://ninite.com/ ставишь галочки, качаешь необходимый дистрибутив, все остальное ставится из веб-инсталлеров каждой отдельной программы.

Comment: я же говорю что мне для личной практики это нужно